# Access Query - Convert Date Range to Individual Date

Tags: sql, ms-access, date-range

I have been looking for a solution for a bit of time now and saw some other subjects about this but I haven't been able to solve my issue.

I have a table "Data" that contains values for specific date ranges:

```
|Arrival Date | Departure Date | Volume
| 01/01/2017  | 04/01/2017     |    6
```

I want to get the below result:

```
| CalendarDate  | Volume
| 01/01/2017    |    2
| 02/01/2017    |    2
| 03/01/2017    |    2
| 04/01/2017    |    0
```

I have created a Calendar with my individual Dates which I am using in my query. I have then made the below query trying to use what I've found on the web, but the result of this query is always empty:

```sql
SELECT 
  Dates.CalendarDate, 
  Sum([Volume]/DateDiff("d",[Arr Date],[Dep Date])) AS Vol, 
  Data.[Arr Date], 
  Data.[Dep Date]
FROM Dates 
LEFT JOIN Data 
  ON (Dates.CalendarDate = Data.[Arr Date]) 
  AND (Dates.CalendarDate = Data.[Dep Date])
GROUP BY 
  Dates.CalendarDate, 
  Data.[Arr Date], 
  Data.[Dep Date]
HAVING 
  (((Dates.CalendarDate)>=[Data].[Arr Date] 
  And (Dates.CalendarDate)<[Data].[Dep Date]));
```

Now if I change it directly in the SQL to the below, it does work. My only issue is that when I try to get back to the Design Mode, Access says that this code cannot be represented into Design Mode and then breaks the connections. However I need to get this done through the Design Mode to make sure some of the users will be able to modify the query even if they don't know anything about SQL.

```sql
SELECT 
  Dates.CalendarDate, 
  Sum([Volume]/DateDiff("d",[Arr Date],[Dep Date])) AS SommeDeNuitées, 
  Data.[Arr Date], 
  Data.[Dep Date]
FROM Dates 
LEFT JOIN Data 
  ON (Dates.CalendarDate < Data.[Dep Date]) 
  AND (Dates.CalendarDate >= Data.[Arr Date])
GROUP BY 
  Dates.CalendarDate, 
  Data.[Arr Date], 
  Data.[Dep Date];
```

Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Left Join on something other than an "equals" sign?  Never seen that before...  I think you need to strip this down to actual fields that exist and that you want to pull.  Take out all the formulas for now, they're clouding the picture.  Get the query to return the correct data first, then worry about what you're going to do with it.  Also, I'm unclear on how you're extrapolating the data.  How do you know that 1/1/2017 has a volume of 2?

Comment: Both your query and the one in Gustav's answer will not create a single record for each calendar date. For example if you have two `Data` records with overlapping but not the same Arrival and Departure dates, the query will create a separate set of Calendar Date records for each of the two instead of aggregating them. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: @JohnnyBones - I don't know for sure that a specific date has a volume of 2, but for my purpose that would be enough to spread this data equally on every date. In regards to the left join, I just wanted to make sure I get all records from the Calendar. Even if there is no volume on one night, I need to have it.

Comment: @SunKnight0 That's a good point, I want indeed to aggregate all data on one date, and not have any duplicated dates.

Comment: If you remove the arrival and Departure dates from both SELECT and GROUP BY, it should do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a "where join":

```
SELECT 
  Dates.CalendarDate, 
  Sum([Volume]/DateDiff("d",[Arr Date],[Dep Date])) AS SommeDeNuitées, 
  Data.[Arr Date], 
  Data.[Dep Date]
FROM Dates 
WHERE 
  Dates.CalendarDate < Data.[Dep Date] 
  AND 
  Dates.CalendarDate >= Data.[Arr Date]
GROUP BY 
  Dates.CalendarDate, 
  Data.[Arr Date], 
  Data.[Dep Date];
```

Comment: Without specifying a join, isn't this going to create a Cartesian by default?

Comment: The parser may be clever. Besides, what other options would there be? Aside for teaching the users SQL, of course.

Comment: @Gustav Thanks you for your answer. It actually works fine, however as SunKnights pointed out (which I didn't think of), is that I now get duplicated dates if I have another date range overlapping another one, instead of having the sum of all volumes for a specific date.

Comment: That sounds right. Then, I guess, you are left with your original query. Perhaps you can split it into a main and a subquery for making editing possible.